# Social Plugins using addthis.com

Tags: html, facebook-like

I am trying to use 3rd party [addthis.com](http://addthis.com) for adding social plugins to my own website. i got my code from their site, when i am putting this code in my html document its functioning and interface is same as i wanted. **but, i am unable to link it with my social sites account/page and the same**

```
<code><body>
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_floating_style addthis_counter_style" style="left:50px;top:50px;">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="box_count"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_tweet" tw:count="vertical"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_google_plusone" g:plusone:size="tall"></a>
<a class="addthis_counter"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true};</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-515b2dbc1a232bc9"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
</body></code>
```

Please help me to link this with my social page. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If im not wrong, you will need to use a different code as that code is just a "Global Share" which means that it will just share the page and not a particular page. You might find more info directly from the URL you are using.

You might want to have a look on this page:

https://www.addthis.com/get/follow#.UV3Dy6KG2rI

With Regards,
Mee

Comment: i followed the link, and what you are answering suits only for the link you have provided but not my question. I you will run this code you can find the facebook - like option too , when you will like it counter will increase but not for the page i wants to associate with the like button. (in case of facebook)

Comment: Right, so probably you will need to create separate rules for each page. What is your website, may I know so that I can have a look on it?